# How to reslove: Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): state.xx is not iterable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I send a number of files and some other data via redux and axios to my backend. However, when I do so, I get the following error message `Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): state.story is not iterable`. Although the error occurs in my react js fronted, the data is successfully sent to my backend. I checked my entire reducers what is making `state.story` not iteratable, but i dont see it. Please see below my reducers for stroy:

```
const initialState = {
  story: [],
  isFetching: "idle",
  count: null,
  next: null,
  previous: null,
};

export default function (state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
case GET_STORY_REQUEST:
      return {
        ...state,
        isFetching: "loading"
      };

case GET_STORY_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        story: action.payload,
        isFetching: "success",
        count: action.payload.count,
        next: action.payload.next,
        previous: action.payload.previous,
      };

case GET_STORY_FAILURE:
      return {
      isFetching: "failure"
      };

case GET_SINGLE_STORY:
     return {
        ...state,
        story: state.story.filter(story => story.id !== action.payload)
      };

case DELETE_STORY:
      return {
        ...state,
        story: state.story.filter(story => story.id !== action.payload)
      };

case EDIT_STORY:
      return {
        ...state,
        story: state.story.filter(story => story.id  !== action.payload)
      };

case ADD_STORY:
      return {
        ...state,
        story: [...state.story, action.payload]
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

I now wonder how i can make state.story iterable? I am happy for any hint.

Comment: @KyleLambert You can use spread with empty arrays: `let emptyArray = []; console.log([...emptyArray, 1, 2])` returns a new array and there is no error. However, if you're trying to spread an object inside an array, you receive an unhandled rejection error.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `action.payload` is an object inside your reducer's `GET_STORY_SUCCESS` case as you're also using its `count`, `next`, and `previous` property on the next few lines.

Maybe the `story` array is on another property, like `action.payload.story`, `action.payload.data`?

```
case GET_STORY_SUCCESS:
  return {
    ...state,
    story: action.payload, // <= story is no longer an array
    isFetching: 'success',
    count: action.payload.count,
    next: action.payload.next,
    previous: action.payload.previous,
  };
```

If you're trying to create a new array by spreading an object, the error message is *"Uncaught TypeError: XXX is not iterable"*

```
let emptyArray = []
console.log([...emptyArray, 1, 2])
// => [1, 2]

// BUT
let object = {}
console.log([...object, 1, 2])
// => Uncaught TypeError: object is not iterable
```

Comment: Actually you are right. The story had a different data Structure, so i had to adopt that. Thanks for the clarification :)

Comment: No problem, @dan_boy. I'd appreciate if you could accept my answer if it helped you solve your problem. :)

Comment: Allright. Might add the information that i have to recheck the data structure / did the data structure change so that new data structure is not iterable any more.  than i can accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are iterating over object. Print story in the console and check whether it is an array or an object. I think you need to iterate over story.data or something like this.